# Why was Harry given his own room?

Tags: harry-potter

Do we know why the Dursleys gave Harry a proper bedroom after Philosophers Stone?

From their viewpoint it would seem to have been a mistake, as his rescue in Chamber of Secrets would have been harder, if not impossible, had he still been sleeping under the stairs.